# C# - Static member vs instance member

Tags: c#

What are the advantages of a static member over instance member?

Comment: Personally I prefer not to use static classes/functions if it is not absolutely needed, especially when it comes to threads.

Comment: Knowing that a method doesn't mutate the state of an object is a big deal, makes it much easier to figure out how the code works. It is faster as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instance methods can use both instance state and static (ie: global) state, while static methods can only use static state (ie: static variables).

So if you, as a caller, call a static method, you are sure it will not modify an instance state.

This also means you are not sure it will not modify a static state. If it does, then it is not "thread safe", which means 2 methods can not call this static method at the exact same time (using 2 CPUs but the same memory).

Of course any static method can be replaced by an instance method, but then all calls to this method will need to create an object first. Creating an object uses CPU and memory (it allocates a block for all instance variables, if any), and adds 1 line in your code, making it less readable.
To mitigate this you can use Singleton instance, which has the advantage of being more flexible as you will be able to switch the Singleton class used by changing it only in one place.
Singleton instances are either stored as public static variables, or in a IOC container (like [unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203101.aspx)). The advantage of using the IOC container is that you will be able to share the singleton instances with external libraries, and no static variable is needed (other than a singleton instance of the IOC container itself).

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 nice....sorry. Singleton instance?

Comment: singleton : design that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object in a program. Ie: there is only one "new MyObject()" throughout the app.

Answer (score 6):

Classes typically represent the blueprint for something, take a person for example we could define a class like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

by making this an instance class, we can have multiple 'people' instantiated, each of which contain different values

```
var person1 = new Person { FirstName = 'Fred', LastName = 'Bloggs' };
var person2 = new Person { FirstName = 'John', LastName = 'Smith' };
```

It doesn't make sense for Person to be static because not every person has the same values.

However, lets take another example - we want to maintain a counter value across the entire application:

```
public static class Counter
{
    public static int Count { get; set; }
}
```

In this case it makes sense to make the counter static, that way there is only one copy in memory and all references point to the same thing.

Comment: This is a simple to understand example, very well explained.

Answer (score 2):

> wht's the big deal in creating an object, to access a behavior of a class

If it is a behaviour of a class and has impact on the class then it should not be static in the first place.

Only those fields should be made static that should remain same for all objects that are instantiated like `connection string`

Whereas only those methods should be made static that have no impact on the behaviour of the class. like you have pointed out yourself calculate sum of 2 variables.

Answer (score 2):

> why would i need a static function, over a member function

Even if your class doesn't have any state, try to override behavior with static method:

```
public class Foo
{
   public virtual Bar() {}
}
```

Try to implement interface and inject interface implementation with a static method:

```
public interface IPlugin
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

The last, but not least. It's a best practice to make static methods thread-safe. Do you really want to make *every* method you write thread-safe?